# How to implement gaze tracking in drowsiness detection system

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, dlib, imutils

```
        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            COUNTER += 1

            if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
                alarm_sound.play()
         
        else:
            COUNTER = 0

        if distance > MAR:
            current_time = time.time()
            if current_time - start_time <= 20:
                yawn_counter += 1
                cv2.putText(frame, f"Yawn count: {yawn_counter:.2f}", (10, 60),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            else:
                if yawn_counter >= YAWN_COUNTER_THRESHOLD:
                    alarm_sound.play()
                    cv2.putText(frame, "YAWN ALERT!", (10, 30),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                yawn_counter = 0
                start_time = time.time()
```

This is my code I want to implement gaze tracking but can't do the code.
I could not figure out how to implement the code and as well as the code.

Comment: alarm_sound.play()

            # Reset the counter
            COUNTER = 0

    # Check if the eyes are open
    elif COUNTER != 0:
        # Reset the counter
        COUNTER = 0